# Weird hash output

Tags: linux, bash, hash, openssl

I'm trying to create a hash for files in the directory using this script:

```
for file in *.zip; do openssl dgst -sha256 -binary ${file%.*}.zip $file | base64 >> ${file%.*}.zip.base64sha256; done
```

It creates hash like this:

```
b5iQL1fo5r+6osykGr0mcEZ14Xdbn8y0SrFGIuzMfeRvmJAvV+jmv7qh7OUavSZwRnXhd1ufzLRKsUYi7Mx95A==
```

But for terraform and AWS Lambdas I need a shorted hash value. I can get by using terminal and command like this:

```
openssl dgst -sha256 -binary archive.zip | base64 >> hash.base64sha256
```

And output is `b5iQL1fo5r+6osykGr0mcEZ14Xdbn8y0SrFGIuzMfeQ=`

So the question is: how I can retrieve short version of hash? It's required by terraform and AWS (when hash value is long - lambda are going to redeploy every time)

Comment: The hash length isn't relevant to terraform, only if it matches. There are many ways to generate a hash, but terraform can generate this value itself with [filesha256](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/filesha256), or by archiving in terraform with the [archive_file data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/archive/latest/docs/data-sources/archive_file). If you need to hash a full directory, this can be done with [fileset](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/fileset) and combined with hash operation or null_resource triggers.

Comment: In any case, if you're set on following the pattern in your question, you can just pass your string to the [sha256](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/sha256) function to get a hash of that base64 string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you decode the "long" base64 you'll see that it's the same sequence of bytes repeated. That's because here

```
openssl dgst -sha256 -binary ${file%.*}.zip $file
```

you are specifying the file twice, once removing the extension and then re-adding it as .zip in `${file%.*}.zip`, the other plainly as `$file`. This results in outputting the concatenated hash for both inputs (that are the same). To fix this, just specify it once:

```
openssl dgst -sha256 -binary "$file"
```

(with quotes to avoid problems with whitespace in shell expansion)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of
`for file in *.zip; do openssl dgst -sha256 -binary ${file%.*}.zip $file | base64 >> ${file%.*}.zip.base64sha256; done`

try

`for file in *.zip; do openssl dgst -sha256 -binary ${file%.*}.zip | base64 >> ${file%.*}.zip.base64sha256; done`